# How to obtain a matrix by adding one more new row vector within an iteration?

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am generating arrays (technically they are row vectors) with a for-loop. a, b, c ... are the outputs.

Can I add the new array to the old ones together to form a matrix?

```
import numpy as np
# just for example:
a = np.asarray([2,5,8,10])
b = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
c = np.asarray([2,3,4,5])
... ... ... ... ...
```

I have tried `ab = np.stack((a,b))`, and this could work. But my idea is to always add a new row to the old matrix in a new loop, but with `abc = np.stack((ab,c))` then there would be an error `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`. 
Can anyone tell me how I could add another vector to an already existing matrix? I couldn´t find a perfect answer in this forum.

Comment: Do you have to use `numpy`? If what you're saying is your only objective - `list.append(...)` would be the way to go.

Comment: How about [`np.concatenate(...)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I personally think ```numpy``` would make my further analysis with the data easier so I would say yes. Nevertheless, your idea is still helpful since I can append the new elements with ```list.append()``` during iteration and convert the list to np.array in the end.

Comment: Many SO answers recommend list append followed by one array creation step.  Repeated `concatenate` is less efficient, and more error prone. In your case you need to **very close** attention to array shapes - at each step in the iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`np.stack` wouldn't work, you can only stack arrays with same dimensions.

One possible solution is to use `np.concatenate((original, to_append), axis = 0)` each time. Check the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

You can also try using [np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Comment: Well, ```np.concatenate(,axis=0)``` would not append the new array to a new row, it just continues to add the new array after the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the ideas from everybody, the best solution of this problem is to append `nparray` or `list` to a list during the iteration and convert the list to a matrix using `np.asarray` in the end.

```
a = np.asarray([2,5,8,10])  # or a = [2,5,8,10]
b = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])   #    b = [1,2,3,4]
c = np.asarray([2,3,4,5])   #    c = [2,3,4,5]
... ... 

l1 = []
l1.append(a)
l1.append(b)
l1.append(c)
... ...
```

`l1`don´t have to be empty, however, the elements which `l1` already contained should be the same type as the `a`,`b`,`c`

For example, the difference between `l1 = [1,1,1,1]` and `l1 = [[1,1,1,1]]` is huge in this case.